# Singleton Class ArrayCollection within Flashbuilder (Mobile) empty?

Tags: android, apache-flex, singleton, flash-builder

I am currently trying to implememnt a Singleton Class in order to store a ArrayCollection of items that I can then access and manipulate across the lifecycle of my app. I have created the below Singleton Class that is designed to hold the ArrayCollection information:

```
package valueObjects
{
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;  

    [Bindable]
    public class Model
    {
        private static var instance:Model = new Model();

        public var ids:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        public function Model()
        {
            if(instance)
            {
                trace("New instance cannot be created. Use Singleton.getInstance()");
            }
        }

        public static function getInstance():Model
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

I have then created the following code on the Main Deafult page for my application so that the ArrayCollection is populated as soon as the app is initiated:

```
        import valueObjects.Model;          

        protected var models:Model = new Model();

                private function loop():void
        {
            var index:int;
            for( index = 0; index < compsCollection.length; index++ )
            {
                trace( "Element " + index + " is " +  compsCollection[index].comp_id );
                            models.ids.addItem(compsCollection[index].comp_id);
                trace(models.ids.length);
            }               
        }
```

The ArrayCollection in the Singleton Class is being populated as the trace statement that I have entered into the loop clearly shows the build of of data in the ArrayCollection. However then when I move to another view within the application I then try to access this ArrayCollection within the Singleton Class with the following code:

```
import valueObjects.Model;

protected var models:Model = Model.getInstance();
protected var test:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

protected function view1_viewActivateHandler(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void
            {

                var index:int;
                trace("Array Length =" + models.ids.length);
                for( index = 0; index < models.ids.length; index++ )
                {
                    trace( "Element " + index + " is " + models.ids[index].comp_id );
                    test.addItem(models.ids[index].comp_id);
                }   
                testbox.text = test.toString(); 
            }
```

Now the problem I am having is that when I try to access this ArrayCollection(ids) it appears to be empty for some reason. I have included a trace statement that also says that the length of the ArrayCollection is "0". Can anyone please help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
public static function getInstance():Model
{
    if(instance == null)
      instance= new Model();

    return instance;
}
```

here no need of assigning to variable

```
protected var models:Model = Model.getInstance();
```

use directly like

```
Model.getInstance().ids = new ArrayCollection();
```

Try this,
this might be helpful to u.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I have changed the Singleton Class (getInstance) to be what you suggested in your first piece of code and left the rest unchanged, I then removed the assignment of the variable from the view that is tring to access the ArrayCollection and finally I changed all the access parameters to the ArrayCollection to be like you said "Model.getInstance().ids.length". Once I have tested this I still get the ArrayCollection length returning 0 for some reason. This is really annoying can you help further??

Comment: I have also looked into using FlexGlobals however I couldnt get these to look at an ArrayCollection properly on my Main default view as it was saying it wasnt set or initated, I would really appreciate some help on sorting this issue as I really need to access global variables within my app. Thanks

Comment: @user723858 Now I got it,make the instance as public

Comment: Hi, I just changed the following line in the Singleton Class: "public static var instance:Model = new Model();" which now makes it "public" instewad of "private". However the app crashes out as soon as I start it saying "Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." which occurs at the line I have just changed, any ideas or did i do it wrong lol?? Thanks

Comment: dont make the instance there new Model(); because we can make it in i n getinstance. I think the static variable creates first. so u got error

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick replies i really appreciate it. I have changed the code to "public static var instance:Model;" which got rid of the error however the Trace statement on my view still returns a length of "0" for the ArrayCollection, it like the data is being removed and a new ArrayCollecttion of that name is being re-created. Any ideas? I have checked the Trace statement when the app is first initalised and it is defo being populated, but its like once i change to another view the data is gone and i dont know y?

Answer (score 0):

In your main Class, change new Model() to Model.getInstance().  However, you are still in the initial stages of your project, and you have an opportunity to avoid the problems Singletons will cause you http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/ .  I'd encourage you to use Dependency Injection (either direct, by simply using the data property, or more abstractly, by using a Dependency Injection Framework, such as Robotlegs, Swiz, Mate, or Parsley).

Comment: Are you suggesting I use the persistance manager to store the ArrayCollection in my Project?

Comment: I'm saying that one way you could do it is to put a reference to your AC in the second argument of pushView.  Or you could use a Framework, which watches for the new View to be added to the display list and gives it what it needs.  Or, you could create something that acts sort of like a framework by listening for ADDED_TO_STAGE, catches the new instance, and gives it the info it needs.  There are all kinds of things that you can do that won't lead you to tangle yourself up in the morass you'd invite by using Singletons.